# Return at least one Completable Future when combining two futures in case of exception

Tags: multithreading, java-8, completable-future

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
     return "hello";
 });
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
     return "world";
 });
```

I need to combine 2 futures to get `hello world` so I'm doing something like this

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = future1.thenCombine(future2, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
result.join(); // this prints hello world
```

Now my challenge is if any of the above futures fail with an exception it should return at least partial response.

If `future1` fails then output should be `hello`

If `future2` fails then output should be `world`

If both are successful then output should be `hello world`

I tried using `CompletableFuture.anyOf()` which would return at least one completable future when combining two completable futures if any of the future fails. In real world considering `future1` and `future2` are API calls how can we tell which one failed with exception and return the response dynamically.

Comment: Perhaps using [`exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally(java.util.function.Function)) to return a default "empty" value upon failure will work for you. E.g., `future1.exceptionally(e -> "").thenCombine(future2.exceptionally(e -> ""), (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2)`.

Comment: Or `future1.thenCombine(future2, String::concat).exceptionally(e -> (future1.isCompletedExceptionally()? future2: future1).join())`

Comment: @Holger So you are using a ternary operator to check the exceptions that is the only difference from above answer?

Comment: @Slaw I tried your approach and it works. Thank you!

Comment: The difference is 1) if both fail, my solution will complete exceptionally rather than with an empty string, 2) only one `exceptionally` stage chained, and 3) no string concatenation if only one non-exceptional result